# The online swf games are which information can see about us?

Tags: flash, game-engine, mac-address

I have an online swf game that I play via Adobe Flash Player. We wonder that data the swf game can read from us for privacy. Maybe MAC Address, Motherboard name or IP? Thanks.

Comment: IP-address, yes, any outgoing connection will reveal your IP, Flash or not. MAC or Motherboard — no, Flash Player does not provide access to those, *normally*. The problem is, Flash Player has a history of security vulnerabilities (search for *adobe player security issues*, it's a read to make one's day), exposing your Motherboard make is the least of the possible problems.

Comment: **UPD**: Just a tidbit of information, **AIR** runtime has the capability (*but browser's Flash Plugin still does not have it*) to read the **MAC**-address(es) of your network adapter(s): https://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetworkInterface.html#hardwareAddress